# Not executing statements in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a beginner and I started learning from API with the help of JQuery, unfortunately I encountered one error that I can't deal with. Well, one of the instructions in the for loop is not executed during the last iteration (same if there is one iteration).

Anyone could tell me something? This is content of file

```
$.getJSON('http://api.tvmaze.com/schedule?country=US&date=2015-05-30', function(data) {

var image;
var title;
var language;
var rating;

for(i=0; i<3; i++) {

    image = data[i].show.image.original;
    title = data[i].show.name;
    language = data[i].show.language;
    rating = data[i].show.rating.average;
    let staricon = '<i class="fas fa-star fa-lg"></i>';

    if (rating == null) { 

        rating = "<p class='rating'>Rating not available</p>";
        $('.rating').attr("style", "color: red;");
        staricon = "";
        console.log(rating);
    }
     $('.row').append('<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4"><figure class="figure"><img src="'+image+'"><figcaption class="figure-caption">'+title+ " (Language: "+language+")"+'<br>'+staricon+" "+ rating+'</figcaption></figure></div>');


}
});
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: i added, sorry.

Comment: "_one of the instructions in the for loop is not executed during the last iteration_" **Which** instruction?

Comment: Which statement is not executing. Do you see any console errors?

Comment: @takendarkk $('.rating').attr("style", "color: red;");

Comment: Because the rating has yet to be added to the page! You are looking at the DOM and setting the style. Just set the string to have the style!

Comment: @Justinas its screenshot from console.log(rating), look on image -> https://i.ibb.co/5TbdKSh/sss.png

Comment: Why not `$('.rating').css({color: 'red'})`?

Comment: @Justinas ok, this is another way, but this is still not working on the last iteration

Answer (score 0):

You better use css

```
.rating {
   color: red;
}
```

and ditch this statement `$('.rating').attr("style", "color: red;");`

Comment: This working, thanks! btw. could you explain to me in the future why the above
instruction (and any other following) at last iteration not working?

Comment: this statement (`$('.rating').attr("style", "color: red;");`) is jquery setting the color to red on each element matching the selector. In this case elements having the class `rating`. You're adding a new element with that class to DOM after that statement.

Comment: I started to look for a solution to this problem and all I had to do is give the instruction `$('.rating').attr("style", "color: red;");` after this `$('.row').append('<div class=col-sm-6 [...]` So looks that my mistake was that I tried to add an attribute to the class, but the class did not yet exist in the set HTML tag? Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: @romson20 That's right. It would be even better to move that statement out of the loop. The selector will take multiple elements anyway so executing it only once is enough.